# None of the included stylesheets and javascripts are being precompiled

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, production-environment

none this are getting precompiled in the production environment, I tried rake assets:precompile, but still having this problem. someone help please !

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery", "application" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "datatable_page" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "datatable_table" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.dataTables.min' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'gmaps4rails' %>
```

Comment: Your post contains very little information as to what might be the cause of the problem. Try following this guide http://stackoverflow.com/a/13390491/1684530 on how to obtain more details what’s going on when precompiling assets.

Answer (score 0):

the problem here was, in my application.js file the require_tree was last line, I moved it to the top and the problem was solved. and for all the style sheets I included them in my application.html.erb separately. Since my application is small it was not an issue, I wouldnt recommend this though