# Assets pre compile every time I push to Heroku Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I am deploying the rails app on Heroku server. And every time I deploy it to Heroku, assets pre compilation is done. Which slows down the deployment process.

Comment: Follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596912/is-it-possible-to-skip-the-asset-precompile-step-for-a-single-git-push-on-heroku

Answer (score 0):

Sure! You'll need to create a manifest.yml in your_app/pubilc/assets directory.

The file can be blank. But ideally, you precompile everything locally, so deploys to Heroku would be much faster.

Make sure that you also committed the manifest.yml file when you're pushing to Heroku. Something like git add -f your_app/pubilc/assets/manifest.yml and a git push heroku master should suffice.